# TypeScript: interface depending on the types of a (recursive) property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a tree-like data structure. I want to wrap each of the tree nodes with a node-wrapper, which adds additional functionalities to a node. But the same time I want to keep the typings intact. Can anybody help me out with that?

Here is a example showing what I want to achieve

```
const a = { children: [], value: 12 } as Node<number>;
const b = { children: [], value: 'string' } as Node<string>;
const c = { children: [b, a], value: true } as Node<boolean>;

const root = { children: [c]; value: null } as Node<null>;

// wrap node data with some functions, but keep typings stable
const wrappedNode = wrapNode(root);

wrappedNode.value; // type should be => null
wrappedNode.children[0].value; // type should be => boolean
wrappedNode.children[0].children[0].value; // type should be => string
wrappedNode.children[0].children[1].value; // type should be => number
```

My current Approach looks like:

```
interface Node<T, C extends Node<unknown, any[]>[]> {
  children: [...C];
  value: T;
}

interface WrapNode<T, C extends Node<unknown, any[]>[]> {
  children: WrapNode<any, [...C]>[];
  value: T;
  computeValue(): any;
}

function createNode<T, C extends Node<unknown, any[]>[]>(value: T, children: [...C]): Node<T, [...C]> {
  return {
    value,
    children,
  };
}

export function wrapNode<T, C extends Node<any, any>[]>(node: Node<T, C>): WrapNode<T, typeof node.children> {
  const value = node.value;

  return {
    ...node,
    computeValue: () => value,
    children: node.children.map(child => wrapNode(child)),
    //                          ^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //           types are:   C[number]  wrapNode<any, any>(n: Node<any, any>)
  };
}

const a = createNode(12, []);
const b = createNode('str', []);
const c = createNode(null, [b, a]);

const x = wrapNode(c);

x.value; // gives me type null, ok!
x.children[0].value; // gives me any :(
x.children[1].value; // gives me any too :(
```

Is it even possible, with TypeScript? I'm using TypeScript 4.0.2, if that helps. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might want your `WrapNode` interface to look like this:

```
interface WrapNode<T, C extends Node<unknown, any[]>[]> {
    children: { [K in keyof C]:
        C[K] extends Node<infer CT, infer CC> ? WrapNode<CT, CC> : never
    }
    value: T,
    computeValue(): any,
}
```

The important difference here is that the `children` property is a [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) that walks through the numeric indices of `children` and gets the type of each element.

There's not much chance the compiler can actually *verify* that any particular value is assignable to such a mapped type, so you'll probably want to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) inside your `wrapNode()` implementation:

```
function wrapNode<T, C extends Node<unknown, any[]>[]>(node: Node<T, C>): WrapNode<T, C> {
    const value = node.value;
    return {
        ...node,
        computeValue: () => value,
        children: node.children.map(wrapNode) as any, // need to assert here
    };
}
```

And then everything works as you want, I think:

```
const x = wrapNode(c);
x.children[0].value.toUpperCase(); // okay
x.children[0].value.toFixed(2); // error! string can't do that
x.children[1].value.toFixed(2); // okay
x.children[1].value.toUpperCase(); // error! number can't do that
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDB2EMFsFMGcAdwGNoAIBSTwBsBeqBvYVE1AS1ABdoAnAM2TQDkB7AE2gB4AVAGlQDCqaAA9qoNrFSsOnAK6gA1qBYB3UP3CgAngG0AugD4DhwsVIWkACzLY2NaKABcqXQDoPA-QG5zFkgBuOHLQLty+FgC+IBYU1PSMqADqNODwMlx8gsJijpLS7FwKymoaqFp6RiZm-qTWtvaOLgSuANLkoKiK0NosdIL6Tn61pAK6rfo54vkZnBR0tIJZ84sCAqYA-Mmp6YWcAllrpi6g0AG0w1GXpEHYIWG81yRILJDwctQAasHQABQAlC4Ko8rsNRPAWDRKKg6AokJQyCxOqodrNDlM8lJZsUVOpNDoTCZfioOC40fx1oDtmlyYJTEQRqgXqBYNDbiFUABeVAk6BudnQCIjByUOQ0ToMxmkDxuXkgqXPV7vL4-FwArmmAXyhX1OwOZw8wpuXWNUBuSBpX4ommFf7lKTA1AAeidPOg0DYqEoLHtsFo0KstGgT1QkSFJGiw1hoHhiM6SAc4GotKEommWL2ONK+MqxiMvwFDyZNj1TVcMq8VNp7k8RhqwugovF9YVWpDlhLpu1-jDqGGkcsSNZ5S5TMTycKvwAjAAmfgGf7hplD6EAI1HCegSegGV+AHJWTQ9-P9Ivhszh0gN+Od5PQHJsNh56vNKelxfoSJR9bdhxfkgzwsER+R+JdgJNfVdAABn0EC7j5b0AFV4HgWgBHAP0AW8Z1XRYRRwG0YZwM7SCYLgkI3G9AAxMgRA9X4Z0XHDhBoGhIQAQlQQ8KAAcyZLQ92hNgfUoKwkyI40SMcXQp1ggVKJYGi6LYBimJdVA8IIiSIOk2TyIQlhkNQmh0MwtTXVoNiaE4+9IFXRYsFAQTUGEr0xMoYBIyAA)

Comment: Going to test that tomorrow, great! Thanks a lot. :) i will accept it as soon i tested :)

Comment: Great, works fine :) Could you elaborate a bit on the "type assertion" part? Do you mean something like (in wrapNode's return): `return { /*...*/, children: node.children.filter(isNode).map(wrapNode)}`, where `isNode` has signature `isNode(value: any): value is Node`?

Comment: I have a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63952570/typescript-mapping-input-type-t-to-tree-like-type, if you don't mind :)

Comment: The type assertion is the `as any` in the `children` line.  You can't fix it with `isNode()`: the problem isn't that `node.children` might not have `Node`s in it.  The problem is that the compiler only knows that `node.childen.map(wrapNode)` will produce an array of `WrapNode<unknown, any>`s.  It doesn't understand that for each index `i`, if `node.children[i]` is of type `Node<CT, CC>` then `node.children.map(wrapNode)[i]` will be of corresponding type `WrapNode<CT, CC>`.  That's just too high-order of reasoning for the compiler to perform.