# TypeScript: mapping input type T to tree-like type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is a follow-up of [Interface Depending on the Types of a Recursive Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945019/typescript-interface-depending-on-the-types-of-a-recursive-property/63945867#63945867)

Sorry if it looks like "write my code" questions, it's surely not meant to be something like that! I'm just getting started with advanced typings and I find it hard to grasp the possibilities I have to express types. So please bear with me :)

In my code I want to convert an object into a tree structure. The code is already doing that, but I want the types to reflect that properly. The code traverses each property of an object (or items if array) and turn them into nodes.

[See Stackblitz for detailed example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gb9bco?file=index.ts)

My current approach:

```
interface Node<Type, Children> {
  value: Type,
  children: Children[],
}

function treeOf<T>(
  value: T,
): Node<
  T,
  {
    [K in T]: Node<T[K], any[]>[]
  },
>
```

... gives me a TypeScript error:

```
Type 'Node<{ [x: string]: T[any]; }, any[]>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Node<unknown, any[]>[]'.
  Type 'Node<{ [x: string]: T[any]; }, any[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Node<unknown, any[]>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

... and it also cannot handle arrays properly I think, as it considers an array's properties ("push", "pop", ...) instead of its items.

I also tried

```
function treeOf<T>(
  value: T,
): Node<
  T,
  Node<
    {
      [K in T]: T[K];
    },
    any[]
  >
> {
```

... but to no avail.

Again I don't know if this is possible with TypeScript as well, or if I am requesting to much now. But maybe someone can tell me :)

### Stackbitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gb9bco?file=index.ts

Comment: Could you please share code of your treeOf method? Or maybe share a small fiddle? Sorry, it is a little hard to understand the nature of your output tree. Like why result.children[1]; should be Node<[number, string], [Node<number, []>, Node<string, []>]> ? Is index of children a level of a tree?

Comment: Sure. will update soon

Comment: Updated it :) And yes, index is of children

Comment: The obvious problem I see here is that there's no ordering on object keys. TS can't convert `{a: string, b: number}` into the tuple `[{name: "a", value: string}, {name: "b", value: number}]` because it could also be `[{name: "b", value: number}, {name: "a", value: string}]`. If you're happy with `Array<{name: "a", value: string} | {name: "b", value: number}>` that's fine, but it doesn't guarantee that each element exists exactly once.  And having [all possible tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194653/use-tuple-instead-of-array-of-union-within-type) is very taxing on the compiler.

Comment: So what type do you expect to see? What type would you like the compiler to think the children property of `treeOf({a: "", b: 0})` is? I've thrown [this](https://tsplay.dev/KN7yrW) or [this](https://tsplay.dev/kNr4VW) together but I don't know if this is what you're looking for.  No matter what the object-keys-to-array transformation will either be lossy, complicated, annoying, or all three.

Comment: Oh okay, yes that's indeed really hard to read and/or use. Then I think I wanted too much in this case. For `treeOf({a: "", b: 0})` I would like to get as return type "{ name: string; value: {a:"", b: 0}, children: [ {name: string, value: string, children: any[] }, {name:string, value: number; children: any[] ] }`, or maybe `unknown[]` instead of `any[]` or simply `[]` for children